# How to prevent gradle build from failing early?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, javac

I am trying to compile a set of Java files with some external dependencies, but the build fails early without going through all the files. What I would like to achieve is to report all the compilation failures in all files after a single `gradle build` call. How can I force the compiler to continue compiling even after hitting errors?

There is no interdependency between the files I attempt to compile. The compilation failures are only with respect to types defined in external library dependencies.

I tried increasing the heap memory size in `jvmargs`, that doesn't seem to be the problem. I have also tried increasing `-Xmaxerrors`, that only affects the number of errors "printed", not the number of errors to hit before finishing the compilation.

The error count is also not constant for the "bail out early" condition, for different sets of files I get different max error count, so I don't know how the compiler decides to stop.

Comment: what task is failing?

Comment: @George compileJava is the task that’s failing. I get the error messages from the compiler in the output, but it doesn’t list errors from all the files in the project. e.g. it shows 73 errors from a few files, if I fix some of those files, I start to see other files being added to compilation and get different number of errors. As I mentioned in the question, there is no dependency between the files, so errors I fix don’t hide the other errors in the initial attempt.